# Trouble Installing mcrypt library on Mavericks (10.9)

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt, osx-mavericks

I was able to successfully install the mcrypt extension on Mountain Lion but I'm having a difficult time installing the extension on Mavericks.

For reference, I'm following this guide: http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/

The only inconsistency I've noticed is that by running `php -v` from the command line, I'm showing PHP version 5.3.15 - whereas the web server appears to be running 5.4.17.  *I downloaded 5.4.17 to compile mcrypt.*

Basically, everything runs according to plan until the very end.  Rather than installing the shared extensions into the new directory, `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525`, I get a message that says:

`Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/`

**EDIT:**

The issue appears to be that the web server's PHP was compiled with module API: 20100525 and the system is still using 5.3.15 (which is API: 20090626), hence the error.

**I'm assuming you can't (easily) update the system version of PHP. What do I need to do to get the module and PHP APIs to match?**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For reference of others finding this thread..

Here is an automated Mcrypt installer for 10.8 and 10.9.
http://topicdesk.com/downloads/mcrypt/mcrypt-download

Less than a minute to install this way.

Comment: @Philip007 you must have php.ini in place before installing it. `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that php 5.4.17 is located in /usr/bin and 5.3.15 is in /usr/local/bin,

so I:

- created symlinks in /usr/local/bin to phpize and php in /usr/bin.
- After I verified that phpize -v and php were pointing to the correct version, it was simply a matter of recompiling the mcrypt extension.  After doing so, the extensions were installed in the correct directory:

`Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/`

**I think in retrospect all I needed to do was add /usr/bin to my path variable so that it checks /usr/bin before /usr/local/bin.**